# Hadoop Interoperability

Tags: hadoop, language-interoperability, bigdata

I have a doubt in Hadoop related to interoperability.
Can a single zookeeper interact with both Solr and Hbase system ? If yes how is it going to interact. 
Also
Let us consider we have a zookeeper which is interacting with both a Solr system as well as a Hbase system.
The requirement for Solr and Hbase system are different.
How is the zookeeper going to differentiate between the requirements of Solr and Hbase system

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper is a 'dumb' service, it's HBase and Solr that interact with Zookeeper. The way it works is that they'll each have their own set of Zookeeper keys that they write and read, so as long as there is no conflict in the key space then you're good.

Zookeeper is designed to be accessed from a wide range of machines, so as long as both services can interact with the same version of Zookeeper you're set. Think of it like a datastore -- you can have multiple systems interacting with the same datastore.

Here's an example:

Maybe HBase uses `/hbase/flags/abc`, and Solr uses `/solr/flags/abc`, so long as they're not writing to the same path it'll work just fine.

Hope that helps.